# Open one command window and execute a series of commands from it

Tags: excel, command, vba

I would like to open a command window/prompt (e.g. cmd.exe) and pass a single line command to it, wait for it to finish, and pass another command to it, continuing until done and then close the command window.

Thinking about this, I guess I could build a multi-line command list and pass that to the command window and let it execute, continuing with the VBA once the commands are done executing.  However, I would prefer my opening request because it would show how it can actually be done (reuse an open window).

I've found a few things where a single command is run and the window is then closed but it doesn't get reused:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/run-shell-command-via-vba-t3895036.html
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129797

I don't know if these are the right track for me or not.  I've never had a need to run the command window and execute multiple command from inside Excel so this is a new learning opportunity for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear possible the way I wanted but I have a work-around that essentially gives me the same end result, please see [Excel forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/975714-open-one-command-window-and-execute-a-series-of-commands-from-it.html#post3513399).

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the earlier reply, this is possible. Use a string variable to build your list of commands. Follow each command with **vbNewLine**. Then pass the whole string variable to the command shell. The only limitation is that you may reach a string length limitation for your command string variable. In that case put it in a loop and build a separate command string for each iteration in the loop. Here is a short example that creates a shell command to call an executable jar and then pause after the jar has completed. It also displays the command status which is best used if only one command is passed to the shell. vbNewLine is the key though, and what you are looking for.

```
Dim javaCmd As String
Dim javaShell
Set javaShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
javaCmd = "java -jar someSpringjava.jar context.xml inputfile=" & inputfile & vbNewLine & pause
Dim cmdRet As Integer
cmdRet = javaShell.Run(javaCmd, 1, True)
Dim statusMsg = "Return code: & cmdRet
iRet = MsgBox(statusMsg, vbOkOnly)
```

We use this technique to call our [spring-batch](/questions/tagged/spring-batch) job routines from Excel.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy what I'm looking for in the opening paragraph.  I have used the vbCrLf as well running through the shell using `sTemp = objWSshell.Run(Command:="%comspec% /c " & sCommand, windowStyle:=5, waitOnReturn:=True)`